# Extended help on chef-shell commands

Tags: chef-infra

we are running Chef v 11.12.2

In chef-shell typing 'help' returns a list of available commands and then offers to use help with specific command as and argument:

```
SNIP
| cookbooks                | Find and edit cookbooks
| cookbooks.all            | list all cookbooks
| cookbooks.show           | load a cookbook by name
| cookbooks.transform      | edit all cookbooks via a code block and save them
SNIP

Use help(:command) to get detailed help with individual commands

=> :ucanhaz_halp
```

although when I try to find help for the "coobooks" command, I get no more than already had before:

```
chef > help (:cookbooks)

Command: cookbooks
================================================================================

Find and edit cookbooks
================================================================================

 => :ucanhaz_halp
chef >
```

My question is, am I doing everything right?

what's the correct way of getting extended help?

Do you know any resource where ALL these commands are explained in detail ?

i have already seen lots of examples on how to work with chef-shell but none of them mentioned working with the cookbook* commands

Official docs

https://docs.chef.io/chef_shell.html

https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_shell.html

https ://docs.chef.io/debug.html

don't  say much about the commands available.

Update:
This is why I need it:
I'm trying to troubleshoot some ruby code in a cookbook. I want to start chef-shell in client mode, then edit cached cookbooks(not on server!), then add breakpoints between recipes and insert 'binding.pry' in ruby code blocks. The node has a big runlist so i'd be happy to limit it to only particular set of recipes. cookbooks heavily rely on the databags so to make things easier I'd like to use chef-client mode instead of other modes or chef-zero.

Currently it doesn't seem I can change the runlist. It is already prepopulated when in chef-client mode.

Although commands seem self-explanatory, i can't make them work:

```
chef > cookbooks.transform
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) from 
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.2/lib/chef/shell/model_wr??apper.rb:62:in transform' from (irb):9 
...
```

Tried to specify ntp as a sample cookbook :

```
chef > cookbooks.transform 'ntp'
Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Object Not Found" from
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2633:in error!' 
...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? It's hard to give clues like this, the commands are self explanatory (working on the runlist cookbooks)

Comment: I'm trying to troubleshoot some ruby code in a cookbook. I want to start chef-shell in client mode, then edit cached cookbooks(not on server!), then add breakpoints between recipes and insert 'binding.pry' in ruby code blocks. THe node has a big runlist so i'd be happy to limit it to only particular set of recipes. cookbooks heavily rely on the databags.  to make things easier I'd like to use chef-client mode instead of other modes and chef-zero. Currently it doesn't seem I can change the runlist. It is already prepopulated when in chef-client mode.

Comment: although commands seem self-explanatory, i can't make them work: `chef > cookbooks.transform
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.2/lib/chef/shell/model_wrapper.rb:62:in `transform'
        from (irb):9
...
chef > cookbooks.transform 'ntp'
Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Object Not Found"
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2633:in `error!'
...
chef > cookbooks('ntp').transform
`

Comment: If you want to work on cached one use chef-zero mode with the cache as repo and I can't ensure I'm right but I'm pretty sure a `-o cookbook` as argument will do. I'll check tomorow at work, but if you can [edit] your question with what you wish and Hat you tried it will be better for future readers than a bunch of comments.

Comment: Thanks Tensibai, -o is supported by chef-client but not by chef-shell

Comment: the -o option has been added in 11.14.2, can't you upgrade (at least in alst 11.x version as you'll need it to upgrade your server one day anyway) ?

Comment: Thanks Tensibai, for now i'm troubleshooting using chef-zero mode of chef-client. but still, how to use coobooks.transform in chef-shell?

Comment: `cookbooks.transform`is aimed at modifying/listing all cookbooks on the chef_server, it expect a code block... [Reread here](https://docs.chef.io/debug.html#manage) to an overview on chef-shell and what it does, but you should more look at the recipe mode than into the cookbooks one.

Answer (score 0):

One has to remember that chef-shell is a REPL, it is irb with chef libs loaded.
so all these commands are just ruby methods, they take arguments and return values.
So the best help (and with examples) is found in comments of the source code here:

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/shell/ext.rb

On my local installation the file is located here

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.2/lib/chef/shell/ext.rb

these commands help you manipulate ruby objects representing cookbooks/nodes/environments/databags/etc. but not files. So you can technically do in-memory editing.
One thing I find chef-shell particularly helpful is exporting databags or just some items:

```
File.new('databags/databagname/itemname.json','w').puts databags('databagname').show('itemname').raw_data.to_json
```